# Ruby on Rails: Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError (Win 10)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip, windows-10

I'm having issues uploading images to my Rails app. I've downloaded ImageMagick and installed the Paperclip gem, but I keep getting the following error:

```
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError>
```

I have the following line in my development.rb file:

```
  Paperclip.options[:command_path] = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin'
```

And here's what my model looks like:

```
class Movie < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :user

has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "400x600" }
validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

I'm running Rails version 5.0.0 and on Windows 10. I've reinstalled ImageMagick several times, but still no luck. And I've tried solutions I found on this site and others, but I still keep getting the error. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: is this the directory that your machine gave you when you ran `which convert` ?

Comment: No that's from the instructions on Paperclip's github page. How do I run which convert on my command prompt?

Comment: You should just be able to run it from the command line and it should return the path. It explains here in the documentation: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#image-processor

Comment: My command prompt's telling me 'which' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. Maybe I don't have ImageMagick installed properly. I'll try reinstalling it again.

Comment: Yeah it should return the path. Follow the instructions under 'manual installation' and let me know if the `which convert` command returns a path

Comment: So I reinstalled ImageMagick and still couldn't run which convert. However, I did a search and found out that Imagemagick 7 uses the "magick" command in place of "convert". When I ran "magick convert", it brought up a bunch of general copyright info about ImageMagick followed by this line: Usage: convert [options ...] file [ [options ...] file ...] [options ...] file. Is this what I'm supposed to find?